# IP address different on Mac vs. PC?

Tags: windows, macos, ip, dhcp

I have a Mac on the Wi-Fi network and my colleagues have Windows, also connected by Wi-Fi.

Why is my IP address totally different from theirs? e.g. mine is 192.x.x.x theirs is 10.x.x.x.  We on the same network?

Comment: A detailed output of "ipconfig/all" command on Windows and "ifconfig" on Mac would be helpful.

Comment: OK done that - now what am i looking for in all this output on mac?

Comment: Can't figure it out

Comment: use whatsmyip.org to find your internet IP.. ipconfig is your internal network IP

Comment: Do you have an actual problem or are you just curious why this is? Have you enabled DHCP in Network Preferences? Do your system/network administrators give out IP addresses manually, perhaps?

Comment: It sounds like the mac is connecting to different router. Have you verified that the connection names are the same?

Comment: The reason they are different is your not connecting to the same network.

Comment: @TheLearner Update your Question with the output of the two commands @Frank asked for. And actually, on the Mac, also do an `ipconfig getpacket en1` (Replace `en1` with the interface identifier for the wireless card on you Mac. For example, on a MacBook Air, this will be `en0`.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mac probably isn't connecting to the domain like the microsoft ones are, so the microsoft ones are getting ran through the domain and are given special IPs and your mac isnt. As such, you probably couldn't "see" their computers, but they can see one another?

Answer (score 0):

If you're really on the same Wi-Fi network, you may have more than one DHCP server on your network. DHCP servers are what give out the IP address leases on the network. The DHCP protocol allows for multiple, even conflicting, DHCP servers on the network. It just leaves it up to the DHCP client implementations to figure out their own way of selecting which offered DHCP lease they want to choose. Mac OS X tends to pick the DHCP lease offer with the most DHCP *options* defined. DHCP options are additional configuration parameters besides the IP address, like which default gateway router to use or which subnet mask to use or which WINS server or LDAP server to use. Maybe the Windows clients just take whichever lease offer they see first.

The output of `ipconfig getpacket en1` (replace `en1` with the correct interface identifier as necessary) on the Mac will tell you more information about the DHCP lease you got, and what server gave it to you.